# Type Annotation Location Erasure

Tags: java, reverse-engineering, bytecode

I'm currently experiencing a strange scenario where it appears that some of the TypeAnnotation coordinate/path data ends up getting erased.  The interface below, while obviously not anything you'd see in actual code (this is just for experimental purposes), yields what appears to be erased coordinate data.

```
public interface WhackedOutCoordinates<M extends 
      @Whoopy Derpable<@Whoopy ? extends Comparable<@Whoopy M>>
     &@Whoopy Comparable<@Whoopy List<? super @Whoopy M>>
     &@Whoopy Serializable> {}
```

The output from javap is as follows:

```
0: #10(): CLASS_TYPE_PARAMETER_BOUND, param_index=0, bound_index=1
1: #10(): CLASS_TYPE_PARAMETER_BOUND, param_index=0, bound_index=1, location=[TYPE_ARGUMENT(0)]
2: #10(): CLASS_TYPE_PARAMETER_BOUND, param_index=0, bound_index=1, location=[TYPE_ARGUMENT(0), WILDCARD, TYPE_ARGUMENT(0)]
3: #10(): CLASS_TYPE_PARAMETER_BOUND, param_index=0, bound_index=2
4: #10(): CLASS_TYPE_PARAMETER_BOUND, param_index=0, bound_index=2
5: #10(): CLASS_TYPE_PARAMETER_BOUND, param_index=0, bound_index=2
6: #10(): CLASS_TYPE_PARAMETER_BOUND, param_index=0, bound_index=3
```

The 2nd part of the class signature intersect

```
@Whoopy Comparable<@Whoopy List<? super @Whoopy M>>
```

seems to have all of its TypeParameter Annotations pointing to one location, indicated by

```
3: #10(): CLASS_TYPE_PARAMETER_BOUND, param_index=0, bound_index=2
4: #10(): CLASS_TYPE_PARAMETER_BOUND, param_index=0, bound_index=2
5: #10(): CLASS_TYPE_PARAMETER_BOUND, param_index=0, bound_index=2
```

As we can see the 1st part of the class signature intersect

```
      @Whoopy Derpable<@Whoopy ? extends Comparable<@Whoopy M>>
```

retains its annotation typeref/coordinate/path data indicated by

```
0: #10(): CLASS_TYPE_PARAMETER_BOUND, param_index=0, bound_index=1
1: #10(): CLASS_TYPE_PARAMETER_BOUND, param_index=0, bound_index=1, location=[TYPE_ARGUMENT(0)]
2: #10(): CLASS_TYPE_PARAMETER_BOUND, param_index=0, bound_index=1, location=[TYPE_ARGUMENT(0), WILDCARD, TYPE_ARGUMENT(0)]
```

**What is causing the 2nd part of the class signature intersect to lose the internal location of the annotation?**

Answer (score 0):

I have found that this seems to be caused by whatever compiler eclipse (MARS specifically) is using. 
After compiling with javac, I get the following javap output:

```
0: #8(): CLASS_TYPE_PARAMETER_BOUND, param_index=0, bound_index=1
1: #8(): CLASS_TYPE_PARAMETER_BOUND, param_index=0, bound_index=1, location=[TYPE_ARGUMENT(0)]
2: #8(): CLASS_TYPE_PARAMETER_BOUND, param_index=0, bound_index=1, location=[TYPE_ARGUMENT(0), WILDCARD, TYPE_ARGUMENT(0)]
3: #8(): CLASS_TYPE_PARAMETER_BOUND, param_index=0, bound_index=2
4: #8(): CLASS_TYPE_PARAMETER_BOUND, param_index=0, bound_index=2, location=[TYPE_ARGUMENT(0)]
5: #8(): CLASS_TYPE_PARAMETER_BOUND, param_index=0, bound_index=2, location=[TYPE_ARGUMENT(0), TYPE_ARGUMENT(0), WILDCARD]
6: #8(): CLASS_TYPE_PARAMETER_BOUND, param_index=0, bound_index=3
```

Ignoring the extra stuff Eclipse throws into the constant pool (hence the #8 (from javac version) instead of #10 (from eclipse version)) we can now see that part 2 of the intersect now has all of its coordinate data when compiled with javac.

If anyone knows of anything within the eclipse compiler config that might be causing it to erase the location data (ie some weird form of optimization) let me know, otherwise I'll report this as a bug.